# Flutter - Datatable - How to set a background color for heading / first row?

Tags: flutter

I have been looking around the API docs, but dont seem to be able to set a background color for header rows. Any tips please?
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Stack`:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: IntrinsicWidth(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              DataTable(
                headingRowHeight: 100,
                dataRowHeight: 100,
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Col1"),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Col2"),
                  ),
                ],
                rows: List.generate(2, (index) {
                  return DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
                    DataCell(
                      Text(
                        "row $index content1",
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(
                        "row $index content2",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]);
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The `100` set as the container's height is the height of the heading row. The [`IntrinsicWidth`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html) is used to set the `Stack`'s width to its children's width.

Result:

[image: res]

Comment: Nice hack! Thanks, I guess it will do it for now, until the API supports it.

Comment: This is a poor hack and should not be recommended. @vicky answer is the correct way.

Comment: How to change shape of headingrow.. I want it it's 2 ends to be rounded..

Answer (score 7):

I have done simply this, That worked for me

`headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {return HexColor('#222D65');},)`

Comment: Thank you. I just used `headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {return Colors.grey;},)`